# Various File Format Structure Information Available

Tags: file

Is there any URL that explains various file format structure information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[File Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format)

[MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME)

[List of file formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_formats)

[Wotsit.org](http://www.wotsit.org/)